# Bounce and increase speed of the ball

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swift2

In Swift, with SpriteKit, I created a ball with an initial constant speed that bounces around the screen. I also created some bricks, when the ball touches the bricks, speed increases, but the problem is that when the ball touches the bricks, it always goes in one direction, 
because rightly, every time the ball hits the bricks:

`ball.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake(CGFloat(speed1+100), CGFloat(speed2+100))`.

I would like that when the ball is going from the top to bottom and it touches a brick, it bounces normaly to top and increase speed, and when the ball is going from the bottom to top and it touches a brick, it bounces normaly to bottom and increase speed.
How can I do it ?

Comment: Can't you just take the `velocity`, multiply it by however much you want to increase the speed, and set it back to the ball's `velocity`?  Would that work for you?

Comment: When the ball hits the bricks it always goes to an x coordinate and y coordinate, because my variable speed1 = 500 and speed2 = -500. I would like that when the ball hits the bricks it normaly bounces in a direction while increses the speed, without entering the coordinates, without a specific direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, from what I understand, you want it to bounce off the bricks, and pick up some speed.  Here's how I would do that:

```
// Place this up where you define globals
float speedMultiplier = 1.1
// Create a new x velocity
float dx = ball.physicsBody!.velocity.dx * speedMultiplier
// Create a new y velocity
float dy = ball.physicsBody!.velocity.dy * speedMultiplier
// Set the velocity to the ball
ball.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake(dx, dy)
```

This should allow it to bounce off the bricks provided the brick's physics bodies are still around (it sounds like they are).  The `speedMulitplier` can of course be adjusted to ramp up the speed by however much you want (or as little).